# Does there exist a sigma-algebra $F$ such that $f$ is $F/\mathbb{B}$ measurable if and only if $f$ is a constant function?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a function from $(\mathbb{R},F) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$ where $\mathbb{B}$ denotes the borel sigma algebra. Does there exist a sigma-algebra $F$ such that $f$ is $F/\mathbb{B}$ measurable if and only if $f$ is a constant function?

We now have to check if $A\in\mathbb{B}$ that $f^{-1}(A) \in F$. But $f^{-1}(A) = F$ since $f$ is constant right? And $F \in F$ so that's fine.

But now if $f$ is $F/\mathbb{B}$ measurable so we know $A\in\mathbb{B}$ implies $f^{-1}(A) \in F$ we want to check what $F$ we need so that $f$ can only be a constant function.

Could anyone help me continue?

Comment: Try to use the functions $1_A$ (1 if $x\in A$, $0$ otherwise). with $A\in F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition should tell you that this sigma-field has to be 'exclusive', in a sense. So what if $F=\{\mathbb{R},\emptyset\}$? This is a sigma-field [*Pf* ?].

If $f$ is $F/\mathscr{B}$-measurable, then $\forall B\in\mathscr{B}$, $f^{-1}[B]\in F$, so...

If $f$ is constant, then $\forall B\in\mathscr{B}$, $f^{-1}[B]=\mathbb{R}\in{F}$, so...